# Why do I have to press back twice to go back in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, url-routing, backbone-routing, html5-history

## [Live Demo of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/TLm28/7/show/)

I have this little example app, where I try to implement a routing system with history. It works as excepted, but for some reason I have to press the back button twice. If you open the console, you can see the logs. When I press for example page1 and page2 and then the back link too, it logs `page2` twice. Why? If I press it again it logs `page1` twice. What? Then it finally goes back. Why do I have to press it twice? Why the logs are so crazy? How can I make it work?

### HTML

```
<div id="home">Home</div>
<div id="page1">Page1</div>
<div id="page2">Page2</div>
<div id="back">Back</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
var app = {};
app.router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'home',
        'page1': 'page1',
        'page2': 'page2',
    },

    home: function () {
        console.log('home');
        Backbone.history.history.pushState('search');
        console.log(Backbone.history.history);
    },

    page1: function () {
        console.log('page1');
        Backbone.history.history.pushState('page1');
        console.log(Backbone.history.history);
    },

    page2: function () {
        console.log('page2');
        Backbone.history.history.pushState('page2');
        console.log(Backbone.history.history);
    },

});

var router = new app.router();
Backbone.history.start();

$(document).on('click', '#back', function () {
    console.log('back');
    console.log(Backbone.history.history);
    Backbone.history.history.back();
    console.log(Backbone.history.history);
    router.navigate(Backbone.history.history.state, {trigger: true, replace: true});
});

$(document).on('click', '#home', function () {
    router.navigate('home', {trigger: true, replace: true});
});

$(document).on('click', '#page1', function () {
    router.navigate('page1', {trigger: true, replace: true});
});

$(document).on('click', '#page2', function () {
    router.navigate('page2', {trigger: true, replace: true});
});
```

Comment: I don't know Backbone, but I would guess that it calls `pushState` for you, so you shouldn't call it yourself.

Comment: @SLaks If I remove that line then it takes me back to the main page. Without calling `pushState()` `Backbone.history.history.state` would be `undefined`.

Comment: Not sure why you're adding pushState calls yourself into the application. Why not allow navigate to do it for you?

Comment: @kinakuta Because without `pushState()` It brings me back to the front page or the previous website.

Comment: Again, why not just use navigate to create your history entries? In general, I'd avoid using navigate to trigger navigation and instead use it to simply manage your browser history.

Comment: @kinakuta Could you show me an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

Does this serve your purpose :

```
$(document).on('click', '#back', function () {
    window.history.back();
});
```

MDN [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.history)

Comment: Did you tried your solution? [Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/TLm28/14/show/): If I copy this function, and delete the `pushState()` it brings me back to the last page. [Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/TLm28/12/show/): If I copy this function and keep the `pushState()` than I have to press back twice again.